# â® characters getting converted to question marks while getting back

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encoding, compression, amazon-sqs

I am having a very weird issue.
I am putting and getting messages from Amazon AWS SQS.
While putting I am compressing and encoding the messages, like this :

```
String responseMessageBodyOriginal = gson.toJson(responseData);
String responseMessageBodyCompressed = compressToBase64String(responseMessageBodyOriginal);
AmazonSqsHelper.sendMessage(responseMessageBodyCompressed, queue, null);
```

Compression and encoding function, looks like this :

```
public static String compressToBase64String(String data) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
    gzip.write(data.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    byte[] compressedBytes = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(compressedBytes));
}
```

On the other hand, while receiving message, this is the code :

```
List<Message> sqsMessageList = AmazonSqsHelper.receiveMessages(queueUrl, max_message_read_count,
                    default_visibility_timeout);
int num_messages = sqsMessageList.size();
if (num_messages > 0) {
   for (Message m : sqsMessageList) {
       String responseMessageBodyCompressed = m.getBody();
       String responseMessageBodyOriginal = decompressFromBase64String(responseMessageBodyCompressed);
   }
}
```

And the function used for decoding and unzipping is like this :

```
public static String decompressFromBase64String(String compressedString) throws IOException {
    byte[] compressedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(compressedString);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedBytes);
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
    gis.close();
    bis.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But the problem is , at times if I pass characters like "**â®**" then those are getting converted to ???? ,  after decoding if I am printing the message.

Not able to figure out why encoding and decoding is behaving weird. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between ASCII and Unicode, how Unicode is UTF-8 encoded?  If not, look on Wikipedia.  You have a mismatch somewhere in your processing stream where data is encoded one way but decoded a different way.

Comment: What is `â®`? Is that two Unicode code points (`0xe2 0xae`)? Or, is it a UTF-8 encoding? If the latter it is not valid since `0xe2` denotes the start of a 3-byte encoding.  Where did that data come from? Without knowing what you think those characters represent it's not really possible to determine where your problem is.

Comment: @JimGarrison These are URLs. URL contain these characters. And I know the difference :) And i made ensure encoding and decoding is done in same way. For example : https://www.amazon.com/beavers-officially-licensed-university-keyscaperâ®/dp/b00ikp2ccq?psc=1

Comment: @JimGarrison Are you able to find where this could have been happening. Thanks in advance though :)

Comment: We cannot help since we don't know what is happening on Amazon SQS. The issue could be there. I'd start by saving the _compressed_ streams and comparing they byte-for-byte to see if something changed.

Comment: @JimGarrison But encoding and decoding functions looks fine right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that encoding is done using the platform's default charset (`data.getBytes()`), while decoding - using UTF-8.

In `compressToBase64String` change `data.getBytes()` to `data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.